# NSTableCellView Rows Aligned Differently on Different Machines

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, storyboard

I'm trying to figure out why, in one NSTableCellView, the rows are aligned properly in the storyboard and when running the app on one MBP. However when running the app on another MBP and iMac the rows appear vertically squished and misaligned - despite pulling the same constraints in the storyboard.

Running the latest Xcode and OS on the machines for reference.

Comment: I have the same issue in one of my apps - but I don't use storyboards, I use xibs and I do the autolayout of the cell views in Interface Builder. And I do the variable row heights manually in code. Still, sometimes on some machines the rows can have wrong heights, or their content can be shifted vertically. I've been debugging forever this topic and have found nothing yet. :/

Comment: For what it's worth: the cause for me was that I was sometimes using `NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup` in the tableView *while* inserting new rows. Somehow it works perfect on 10.11, but creates the kind of issues we experienced in 10.12 and 10.13. The solution was to either not use runAnimationGroup in the tableView or to ensure that its animation has ended before inserting new rows.